# How to create a function that loops through another function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.9 and I have a procedure called list_all_upsells that takes in the beginning of a month and the end of a month. (see sqlfiddle.com/#!15/abd02 for sample data) For example, the below code would list the count of upselled accounts for the month of October:

```
select COUNT(up.*) as "Total Upsell Accounts in October" from 
list_all_upsells('2015-10-01 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2015-10-31 23:59:59'::timestamp) as up
where up.user_id not in
(select distinct user_id from paid_users_no_more 
where concat(extract(month from payment_stop_date),'-',extract(year from payment_stop_date))<>
concat(extract(month from payment_start_date),'-',extract(year from payment_start_date)));
```

The list_all_upsells procedure looks like this:

```
DECLARE
payor_email_2 text;
   BEGIN
FOR payor_email_2 in select distinct payor_email from paid_users LOOP
return query
execute
'select paid_users.* from paid_users,
(
select payment_start_date as first_time from paid_users
where payor_email = $3
order by payment_start_date limit 1
) as dummy
where payor_email = $3
and payment_start_date > first_time
and payment_start_date between $1 and $2
and first_time < $1'
using a, b, payor_email_2;
END LOOP;
return;
END
```

I want to be able to run this for all months that we have records and query the data together in one table like this:

```
Month   | Total Upselled Accounts
---------------------------------
08/2014 | 23
09/2014 | 35
ETC...
10/2015 | 56
```

I have a query to grab the first of each month and last of each month for the months we have been in business:

```
select distinct date_trunc('month', payment_start_date)::date as startmonth
from paid_users ORDER BY startmonth;
```

Last of month:

```
SELECT distinct (date_trunc('MONTH', payment_start_date) + 
INTERVAL '1 MONTH - 1 day')::date as endmonth from paid_users 
ORDER BY endmonth;
```

Now how would I create a function to loop through the `list_all_upsells` and grab the count for each of these months? I.e. the first query for `startmonth` gives me 2014-03-01, 2014-04-01, ...to 2015-10-01 whereas the second query for `endmonth` gives me 2014-03-31, 2014-04-30, ...to 2015-10-31. I want to run the `list_all_sells` on each of these months so that I can get an aggregate count each month of how many upselled accounts we have

My `paid_users` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE paid_users
(
  user_id integer,
  user_email character varying(255),
  payor_id integer,
  payor_email character varying(255),
  payment_start_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

`paid_users_no_more`:

```
CREATE TABLE paid_users_no_more
(
  user_id integer,
  payment_stop_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
)
```

Comment: I am really not good with postgres, but is not it possible to substitute execute with proper joins?

Comment: Hey @GSazheniuk I have no idea :s

Comment: When looking at layers of looping it's almost always way, way faster to convert to using a combined query with subqueries, joins, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your function, so let's start there. The short of it is that (1) you need only a single parameter to indicate the month, using beginning and ending of the month is setting yourself up for problems; (2) you do not need a dynamic query because you are not changing identifiers (table or column names); (3) you do not need a loop; and (4) your logic is wrong. I could also mention that PostgreSQL uses *functions* and that they all start with a line like `CREATE FUNCTION list_all_upsells(...)` but that would be just too picky.

To start with the logic: Apparently a user identified by his email address takes out a subscription from a certain `payment_start_date` until a certain `payment_stop_date` and can do this multiple times. You are looking for those users who took out their first subscription before the month in question, and who started a new subscription in the month in question but not a first subscription. In that case the filter `payment_start_date > first_time` is useless because you already filter for a first subscription being prior to the month in question (`first_time < $1`) and a new subscription (`payment_start_date BETWEEN $1 AND $2`).

Points (1), (2) and (3) really only become obvious when rewriting the query inside the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION list_all_upsells(timestamp) RETURNS SETOF paid_users AS $$
  SELECT paid_users.*
  FROM paid_users
  JOIN (  -- This JOIN keeps only those rows where the payor_email has a prior subscription
    SELECT DISTINCT payor_email,
           first_value(payment_start_date) OVER (PARTITION BY payor_email ORDER BY payment_start_date) AS dummy
    FROM paid_users
    WHERE payment_start_date < date_trunc('month', $1)
  ) dummy USING (payor_email)
  -- This filter keeps only those rows with new subscriptions in the month
  WHERE date_trunc('month', payment_start_date) = date_trunc('month', $1)
$$ LANGUAGE sql STRICT;
```

Since the body of the function has reduced to a single SQL statement, the function is now a `sql` language function, which is more efficient than `plpgsql`. You now supply only a single parameter, which can be any moment in the month you want the data for, so `list_all_upsells(LOCALTIMESTAMP)` will give you the results for the current month. In terms of the query you posted it would be:

```
SELECT count(up.*) AS "Total Upsell Accounts in October"
FROM list_all_upsells(LOCALTIMESTAMP) up
WHERE up.user_id NOT IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM paid_users_no_more 
   WHERE date_trunc('month', payment_stop_date) <>
         date_trunc('month', up.payment_start_date)
  );
```

This, incidentally, really begs the question why you have the table `paid_users_no_more`. Why not simply add a column `payment_stop_date` to table `paid_users`? Where that column is `NULL` the user is still subscribed. But the whole query is rather odd, because `list_all_upsells()` returns new subscriptions during the month, so why bother with cancelled subscriptions at *some other time*?

Now on to your real question:

```
SELECT months.m "Month", coalesce(count(up.*), 0) "Total Upselled Accounts"
FROM generate_series('2014-08-01'::timestamp,
                     date_trunc('month', LOCALTIMESTAMP),
                     '1 month') AS months(m)
LEFT JOIN list_all_upsells(months.m) AS up ON date_trunc('month', payment_start_date) = m
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[Generate a series of months](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) from some starting month until the current month, then count the new subscriptions for each month, possibly 0.

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8ed72/2)

Comment: This is a really great answer and the logic makes perfect sense. I tried running your list_all_upsells create function however and got a syntax error near "SELECT" (5th line) - why is this? @Patrick

Comment: Oh, that was a nasty error. Nothing to do with the `SELECT`. I started working from your code and changing the scalar sub-query in the select list of the main query to a regular `JOIN`: you need to remove the `,` in the second line, after `FROM paid_users`. Took me a while to find that finicky littl'un!

Comment: Hey Patrick - should it be CURRENT_DATE instead of CURRENT_TIME? I get "ERROR:  function list_all_upsells(time with time zone) does not exist
LINE 2: FROM list_all_upsells(current_time) up
             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts." when I do current_time. When i try current_date I get 0 tho

Comment: Ah. `CURRENT_TIME` gives a `timestamp with time zone`. Use `LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead; that gives a normal `timestamp`. I thought the cast would be automatic. Answer updated.

Comment: Hm I don't know why but I get the result as 0 and when I run the last query I only get the month of October returned

Comment: No, the code should just work insofar as I can see. Can you set up a sqlfiddle with some real data? Looking at just lines of code isn't going to be much help.

Comment: Hey patrick - please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/abd02, in this example payor_id 3453 is paying for 6 accounts. They upselled in Jan 2015, Mar 2015 and twice in Apr 2015

Comment: Issue solved, answer updated. See your fiddle for details. The `list_all_upsells()` function is at the bottom of the schema panel. The issue was - primarily - that only a single upseller's email was selected, this is now resolved with a window function. This episode shows the power of example data: always give table definitions, sample input data and desired output data.

Comment: Definitely Patrick. I don't know what's going on now though - the procedure logic looks correct but when I run the final query, I get all 0s for all months except for one month having 1. And I know for sure we are getting upsells all months

Comment: Hey Patrick - I have another question if you are interested in answering! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640278/calculating-churn-rate-with-postgresql-when-users-can-change-payors-but-have-sam